# Dropbox.com not accessible on Yosemite 10.10.3

Tags: macos, dropbox

I've OS X Yosemite 10.10.3. Since sometime dropbox.com is not accessible on my mac. Now since few days dropbox in my finder doesn't sync. I uninstalled it and now I cannot install as dropbox.com doesn't connect. I have done all the updates since updating to Yosemite. The traceout shows that the second last hop blocks the connection.
Could anybody please help me?

Comment: Can you log in in to the Dropbox on-line version (without installing it on your Mac)

Comment: No I can't. The website is unaccessible since months. I can login to my account from other mac and pc and my mobile.

Comment: Could you show us the trace with the problem

Comment: 20  ae13-sjc8-dr02.net.dropbox.com (108.160.174.234)  572.383 ms
    ae11-sjc8-dr01.net.dropbox.com (108.160.174.230)  410.248 ms  508.492 ms
21  108.160.164.19 (108.160.164.19)  628.087 ms  408.700 ms
    108.160.164.25 (108.160.164.25)  409.703 ms
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason your connection time is very long.

Lets test it.

Open the Terminal app located in your Utility folder.

Now type `Ping dropbox.com`

It should come back with something like this

> PING dropbox.com (108.160.172.232): 56 data bytes
>
> 64 bytes from 108.160.172.232: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=19.474 ms

I have about 15 to 20 milli seconds (ms), you are showing few hundreds ms (500). that is definitely not good.

Based on your results you have a Ping (some Internet address) problem while your Internet speed is very good.

Usually that comes from the DNS (Domain name Server), not resolving the Internet address correctly/Fast.

- First lets clean your DNS cache, just in case something is stuck in there.

Use Terminal and run `sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache` enter your password when asked. Now you should have a clean cache and can start over.

- Next would be to run a trace route (to Dropbox) to see where is it going and where it takes forever. In Terminal type `Traceroute Dropbox.com` and wait for it to finish (it takes few moments.
  The first line is to your router and it should be less the 1 ms (I have 0.7 ms). The following lines are other routes (you can see the names of the servers). I end up with 30ms to the dropbox.
- Lets carefully check your Network settings step by step.

TCP/IP -Use DHCP

DNS- we discussed that (but take note how many you have in there and what they are)

Proxies- they should be all off

Hardware- Automatic (MTU-Standard 1500)

- Lets see who is using your Internet. Turn off programs like Mail, Browser, Skype ect. to make that a short list.

Now type `lsof -i -P` in Terminal and look who is still using your Internet.

- There is a small [application/Script that will evaluate all DNS servers](https://code.google.com/p/namebench/downloads/detail?name=namebench-1.3.1-Mac_OS_X.dmg&can=2&q=) around you and recommended which one is fastest for you to use. Give it a try, I use it and it does help with the DNS stuff.
- The following is to just check the content of your Host file. Follow the [instructions here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/129858/46541) to test your Host file setting.

Comment: With Ping dropbox.com I getRequest timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8
Request timeout for icmp_seq 9 and it goes on

Comment: OK, "Huston we have a problem" :)

Comment: Let s try to Ping google. com to test that.

Comment: With Nettop I don't get any dropbox activity. I uninstalled it.

Comment: 64 bytes from 173.194.116.5: icmp_seq=0 ttl=54 time=150.194 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.116.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=149.015 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.116.5: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=159.272 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.116.5: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=156.921 ms

Comment: Above is with google.com

Comment: OK, not so bad (150ms) but still on the slow site (it should be <100ms), Your network speed is not so good! Could you hold the "alt" key and click on the WiFi icon and report the RSSI #, the Transmit Rate #? and the MCS Index #

Comment: RSSI is 59 dBm,  Tx Rate is 39 Mbps, and MCS index is 5

Comment: I've taken my mac to our internet provider as well and the same problem persisted there

Comment: wow...with those kind of numbers you should be getting speeding tickets :) so what is the problem with the Ping ? let me think...while having lunch

Comment: ok, I have to go away for a while, you can check your DNS setting in the syst pref network, and add gooles DNS server 8.8.8.8 and move it to the top. DNS resolves the Internet addresses.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that

Comment: Its already added.

Comment: Many thanks. Your last advice of testing the host file setting and the link worked. I have now access to dropbox website and also able to install it. Many thanks for all your time.

Comment: I am unable to find out how to mark the question done.

Comment: Just checking if you are still a happy user, now that you finally got your dropbox working. And if you could share with us what was wrong with your HOST file.

Comment: Indeed I am a happy user since then. Many problems resolved. You are the best :-). There were dropbox addresses added in my host file, which I could simply delete as told by you [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/129858/46541)